# How to add a new Findbug Rule or import a set of rules in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, findbugs

I have a configuration file for findbugs. I can use it in an ant script. I want to use it also in eclipse.

Is it possible to change the ruleset of Findbugs via importing a new ruleset in Eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid you can't. The properties in eclipse plugins are embedded in a property file.

For instance, for findbugs you can find your configuration in the file `my-project/.settings/edu.umd.cs.findbugs.core.prefs`.

As you can see it contains a flatten version of the xml.

Unfortunately, there is (currently) no tool to import / export the configuration. That could be a nice feature request !

M.

Comment: I know about this configuration file. I wrote a small script to convert the xml into this property file. The problem is if i change the existing detector methods, eclipse recognizes the changes. But I have more detector methods than in Eclipse. Eclipse (or Findbugs plugn in Eclipse )ignores the new methods.

Comment: You can edit the findbugs.xml in the `plugins/edu.umd.cs.findbugs.plugin.eclipse_2.0.1.20120712/findbugs-plugin.jar` to add you rules in there.

Answer (score 1):

When you say "*a configuration file*", do you mean a "[filter file](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/filter.html)"?

If that's the case then, in eclipse:

Go to *Window --> Preferences --> Java --> FindBugs --> Filter files* (tab) --> In "**Include filter files**" select "**Add..**" and choose your xml configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how FindBugs saves its settings in Eclipse, but you might be able to use [Workspace Mechanic](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/workspacemechanic/). It can import and export almost all Eclipse settings between workspaces.